# Arithmetic operations between Django fields belonging to the same class model. Is it possible?

Tags: python, django

I have the need to divide a class field (Value) in Django-admin model with a fixed value (coefficient) in the same class. 
The result of this operation should populate another field (Points) of the same class. Both values are of same type (integers).

For example a user enter a value of '180', then he leaves coefficient to its default '10'. When it saves the new entry it should show up `Points = 18`

So for the moment I defined `'coefficient'` field in Django `models.py` which defaults to 10.
'Value' field is editable as I said above.
I thought to use `F()` to perform math operations between fields however I am not sure if this is the correct tool or there's something simpler.
When I set up the following expression on my model I see alot complaints when I make db migrations.

```
Points = Visits.objects.all().annotate(div=F('Value') / F('Coefficient'))
```

Since I am new to Django I appreciate any help on this, maybe I am misunderstanding something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method-1

Override **`save()`** method of **`Value`** model, as

```
class Visits(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    coefficient = models.IntegerField()
    points = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.points = int(self.value / self.coefficient)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

### Method-2

use [**`@property`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator

```
class Visits(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    coefficient = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def points(self):
        return int(self.value / self.coefficient)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the `save()` method of your model to calculate the `Points` field:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Points = self.Value / self.Coefficient
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You might also want to check for and handle division by zero here.